# Reduce the Average difference

Tags: arrays, algorithm, performance, sorting

Two arrays A,B are given of same length (not sorted).
Make pairs of their entries (one from A and one from B), such that average difference in the entries (|a1-b1|,|a2-b2|,....) is minimum.

I have thought of sorting them and then making pairs of same index entries.
Will this work ?
If yes, how ? else some other solution with proof.

Comment: Does each element of A have to be paired with a unique element of B, such that all Bs are used?

Comment: yes, every element should be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming that this problem can be formally stated as follows: given two n-element vectors A and B, find permutations A' of A and B' of B so as to minimize the L1 norm of A' - B'.

If so, then your proposed algorithm is correct. Suppose that we have a solution with an inversion, that is, a1 matched with b2 and a2 matched with b1 such that a1 < a2 and b1 < b2. The contribution of these pairs to the L1 norm is

```
|a1 - b2| + |a2 - b1| >= |a1 - b1| + |a2 - b2|,
```

where the inequality follows from an inelegant case argument that we defer for the moment. Accordingly, by rematching a1 with b1 and a2 with b2, we decrease the number of inversions without increasing the cost. It follows by induction that the matching with no inversions is optimal.

Case argument: symmetrically (by interchanging A and B), there are three possible interleavings.

```
(1) a1 <= a2 <= b1 <= b2
(2) a1 <= b1 <= a2 <= b2
(3) a1 <= b1 <= b2 <= a2
```

In case (1),

```
|a1 - b2| + |a2 - b1|  = b2 - a1 + b1 - a2
                       = b1 - a1 + b2 - a2
                       = |a1 - b1| + |a2 - b2|.
```

In case (2),

```
|a1 - b2| + |a2 - b1|  = b2 - a1 + a2 - b1
                      >= b2 - a1 + a2 - b1 - 2 (a2 - b1)
                       = b1 - a1 + b2 - a2
                       = |a1 - b1| + |a2 - b2|.
```

In case (3),

```
|a1 - b2| + |a2 - b1|  = b2 - a1 + a2 - b1
                      >= b2 - a1 + a2 - b1 - 2 (b2 - b1)
                       = b1 - a1 + a2 - b2
                       = |a1 - b1| + |a2 - b2|.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** misread the question, the below describes why the sum of differences is *maximized* when you sort the two lists in opposite order

Here is another way to see that the algorithm you described gives you the optimal solution. Note that when you write out `|x - y|` it equals either `x - y` or `y - x`. Thus,

```
|a_1 - b_1| + |a_2 - b_2| + ... + |a_n - b_n|
```

can be thought of as summing the numbers `a_1, ..., a_n, b_1, ... , b_n`, except that exactly `n` of them have their sign flipped. Clearly, this is maximized when you choose to negate the `n` smallest numbers out of `a_1, ..., a_n, b_1, ..., b_n`. And indeed, that is exactly what your algorithm does.

Comment: Wow! Its a nice and different way to look into the problem.
Thanks!

Comment: @user3739969 It's a neat proof, but it seems to be describing the problem of maximizing the sum of differences instead of minimizing.

Comment: Oops, you are absolutely correct. I misread the question. Should I delete the answer now?

Comment: but the approach can be extended for minimum also, i guess.